# MySql wherein for value pair

Tags: mysql

UPDATE `tablename` SET `columnname`=`columnnname`-1 WHERE (`columnname1`,`columnname2`) in ((23,50),(23,50)).

The above code works fine for only one row. It doesn't update the 2nd row having the same value pair. Please Provide a solution.

Comment: Column2 is repeated in your where statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname1=columnname1-1 WHERE (columnname1,columnname2) in ((23,50),(23,50));
```

It will update all subsequent row which satisfying given condition.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: isnt this the same as given in question?

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran in where condition pair contains same columnname `columnname2`,i had changed them with `columnname1,columnname2`.

Comment: by mistake i wrote columname2 in the above question..it's just a typing mistake..one will be columnname1 & the other will be columnname2 ...so the correct query is UPDATE `tablename` SET `columnname`=`columnnname`-1 
    WHERE (`columnname1`,`columnname2`) in ((23,50),(23,50)). Now for this query .. It doesn't update the 2nd row having the same value pair...it only updates the 1st row.....so please help

Comment: I had tried same one,it will update all subsequent records which satisfied given condition.

Comment: @Sagar Gangwal But if the given value pairs are same...then mysql wherein takes only one value pair and updates only one record , i.e , mysql wherein rejects the other value pair which is exactly equal as the former one...but if both the value pairs are different..say (23,50) & (23,51)..then mysql wherein will take both the value pair and will update the records so on correctly...so please provide a solution to my query....if u have any